# Gradle Fails to Sync even on first run

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

i installed Android Studio latest version on windows 10.(what i already did with another version and another windows 10)
it's OK with android SDK but when it wants to load a project it said this:

> Error:(23, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12

and here's the log:

> JsonSyntaxException: Parse exception while reading distributions.json: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mohammad.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: please share build.gradle file

Comment: @Pooya added the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following lines

```
android {
 ...
 ...
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
...
...
}
```